# sort values column CSV java

Tags: java, csv, sorting

I'm trying to sort descending the following CSV based on the values contained in three columns(url,priority,length), in the same way that the `order by` in the SQL language was executed

The starting CSV is the following:

```
url;review;priority;length
1610-bagel-torino;"Ingredienti di qualità.";0;15
1610-bagel-torino;"Il personale è molto gentile.";1;7
7-nani-torino;"Farina buonissima.";0;14
1610-bagel-torino;"Posto carino.";0;9
7-nani-torino;"Arredamento semplice.";1;9
```

And i want to obtain

```
url;review;priority;length
7-nani-torino;"Arredamento semplice.";1;9
7-nani-torino;"Farina buonissima.";0;14
1610-bagel-torino;"Il personale è molto gentile.";1;7
1610-bagel-torino;"Ingredienti di qualità.";0;15
1610-bagel-torino;"Posto carino.";0;9
```

I started with this code but sorting descending only based on the URL and priority columns.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("contexts_file/matching/lessico_frasi/"+context+"_ranking.csv"));
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] arr = line.split(";");
         list.add(arr[0]+","+arr[2]+","+arr[3]);
      }
Collections.sort(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
list.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

With this code the output is the following:

```
url;review;priority;length
7-nani-torino;"Arredamento semplice.";1;9
7-nani-torino;"Farina buonissima.";0;14
1610-bagel-torino;"Il personale è molto gentile.";1;7
1610-bagel-torino;"Posto carino.";0;9
1610-bagel-torino;"Ingredienti di qualità.";0;15
```

The last two lines should be reversed

Comment: (a) Use a proper CSV parser. You have quoted values there, they may contain semicolons, this problem has been solved many times over. (b) When you do that, create an object (POJO) from each row. Objects can easily be sorted using `Comparator` and their getters in all sorts of combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem can be solved using a custom comparator. As you have yourself mentioned that the `order by` clause of SQL for your requirement. In SQL if the property of 2 records is same then the records are compared based on the next property of the `order by` clause.

A good solution is to create a POJO for each of the lines and then use a custom comparator to sort the results.

```
private static void customSortCsv() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Key> list = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.csv"));
    String line;
    int idx = 0;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (idx == 0) {
            idx++;
            continue;
        }
        String[] arr = line.split(";");
        list.add(new Key(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]));
    }

    Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> {
        int c = o2.url.compareTo(o1.url);
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }

        c = o2.priority.compareTo(o1.priority);
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }

        return o2.length.compareTo(o1.length);
    });

    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}

static class Key {
    String url;
    String review;
    Integer priority;
    Integer length;

    public Key(String url, String review, String priority, String length) {
        this.url = url;
        this.review = review;
        this.priority = Integer.parseInt(priority);
        this.length = Integer.parseInt(length);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return url + ";" + review + ";" + priority + ";" + length;
    }
}
```

The above code gives you the desired results. You can further clean the code by using one of the CSV parser libraries present in Java.